# "Failed to get param: timeout expired" Warning

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, opencr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On turtlebot3 burger, always meet below warning--is that relevant or not?

**[WARN] [1557209537.049069]: Failed to get param: timeout expired**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/b53a20ce-706b-11e9-aead-645d86d9e3f6/roslaunch-raspberrypi-947.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.36:41903/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13
 * /turtlebot3_core/baud: 115200
 * /turtlebot3_core/port: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /turtlebot3_core/tf_prefix: 
 * /turtlebot3_lds/frame_id: base_scan
 * /turtlebot3_lds/port: /dev/ttyUSB0

NODES
  /
    turtlebot3_core (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    turtlebot3_diagnostics (turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics)
    turtlebot3_lds (hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.20:11311

process[turtlebot3_core-1]: started with pid [956]
process[turtlebot3_lds-2]: started with pid [957]
process[turtlebot3_diagnostics-3]: started with pid [958]
[INFO] [1557209529.430844]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1557209529.603777]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud
[INFO] [1557209531.923618]: Note: publish buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1557209531.926641]: Setup publisher on sensor_state [turtlebot3_msgs/SensorState]
[INFO] [1557209531.965567]: Setup publisher on firmware_version [turtlebot3_msgs/VersionInfo]
[INFO] [1557209532.248661]: Setup publisher on imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[INFO] [1557209532.299612]: Setup publisher on cmd_vel_rc100 [geometry_msgs/Twist]
[INFO] [1557209532.392218]: Setup publisher on odom [nav_msgs/Odometry]
[INFO] [1557209532.449411]: Setup publisher on joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState]
[INFO] [1557209532.501160]: Setup publisher on battery_state [sensor_msgs/BatteryState]
[INFO] [1557209532.543757]: Setup publisher on magnetic_field [sensor_msgs/MagneticField]
[INFO] [1557209536.624799]: Setup publisher on /tf [tf/tfMessage]
[INFO] [1557209536.707891]: Note: subscribe buffer size is 1024 bytes
[INFO] [1557209536.709910]: Setup subscriber on cmd_vel [geometry_msgs/Twist]
[INFO] [1557209536.828765]: Setup subscriber on sound [turtlebot3_msgs/Sound]
[INFO] [1557209536.944848]: Setup subscriber on motor_power [std_msgs/Bool]
[INFO] [1557209537.015854]: Setup subscriber on reset [std_msgs/Empty]
[WARN] [1557209537.049069]: Failed to get param: timeout expired
[INFO] [1557209537.052940]: Setup TF on Odometry [odom]
[INFO] [1557209537.056981]: Setup TF on IMU [imu_link]
[INFO] [1557209537.060776]: Setup TF on MagneticField [mag_link]
[INFO] [1557209537.064736]: Setup TF on JointState [base_link]
[INFO] [1557209537.086421]: --------------------------
[INFO] [1557209537.090260]: Connected to OpenCR board!
[INFO] [1557209537.094084]: This core(v1.2.3) is compatible with TB3 Burger
[INFO] [1557209537.098039]: --------------------------
[INFO] [1557209537.101721]: Start Calibration of Gyro
[INFO] [1557209538.421965]: Calibration End
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322595/%22failed-to-get-param:-timeout-expired%22-warning/) by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/issues/283#issuecomment-409837518) could help.

> `Failed to get param: timeout expired error` is sometimes occurred due to timeout between OpenCR and Raspberry Pi. But this problem is simply solved by reboot OpenCR.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-07**:
Thanks, so how to reboot the OpenCR? Here reboot I suppose it means SW reboot (some command?) but not hardware reboot.

**Comment by [lohwanyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/83563/lohwanyan/) on 2022-10-04**:
excuse，i encountered the same trouble,did you slove it? and how?